# implementing custom adapter for search view - android

Tags: android, searchview

Here is an example of the searchview adapter that i want to get

[image: image1]

What is the way to implement a custom adapter like this to the default search view on android ?

NOTE: The data will come from a webservice

Comment: well it depends where does your data come from, is it a small static content stored in some list like structure or is it a result of some web request?

Comment: web service request @pskink

Comment: so use `SimpleCursorAdapter` like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19860624/2252830, you would then use it with `SearchView#setSuggestionsAdapter`

Comment: Material Searchview is best

Comment: @AdityaVyas-Lakhan there are many of it which one exactly do u mean ?

Comment: @pskink the link shows again for text only

Comment: then use picasso, glide, volley or any other similar lib